# No baja la caja al añadir más elementos en responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

Me gustaría que mi caja de fondo blanco fuera proporcional al número de elementos añadidos, ya que actualmente se me amontonan con el footer y es algo que no deseo.
Esto pasa en dispositivos celulares, pero en computadoras no pasa.

¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionar eso? Estoy abierto a utilizar Javascript o jQuery de ser necesario, pero estoy seguro que se puede hacer con CSS.

```css
#allSites {
 height:80vh;
 }
 
.box-Main {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #c5cacd;
  height:100%;
}

#site {
  max-height: 200px;
  padding: 1em;
  cursor:pointer;
}
  #allSites{
    height:80vh;
  }
  #allSites > .col-md-6:hover{
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
  }
  /*#site:hover{
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
  }*/ 

  #site a,
  #site a:hover{
    color:#31404d;
    text-decoration:none;
  }

  #site h4{
    font-weight: 800;
  }
  #site p{
    font-size: 0.8em;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-top: 1em;
  }

  #site img{
    margin:0 auto;
    border:1px solid #31404d;
    width: 120px;
    height: 150px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>  
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#F2F2F2;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container header">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-3">
            <h1>asfgd</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-3 col-md-offset-4 col-xs-7 col-xs-offset-2  text-right">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-createSite">Añadir sitio</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                <i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-settings">Mis ajustes</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a id="sessionOut" href="#">Cerrar sesión</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid box-Main border-MainTop">
        <div class="row" id="allSites">

      <div class="col-md-6">
         <div id="site">
           <a href="#">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x150" alt="Mi primer sitio">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <div class="siteContent">
                    <h4>Mi primer sitio</h4>
                    <p>Mi primer sitio, Mi primer sitio, 12345, Mi primer sitio, Mi primer sitio, Mi primer sitio.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>  
          </div>
       </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
         <div id="site">
           <a href="#">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x150" alt="Mi primer sitio">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <div class="siteContent">
                    <h4>Mi primer sitio</h4>
                    <p>Mi primer sitio, Mi primer sitio, 12345, Mi primer sitio, Mi primer sitio, Mi primer sitio.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>  
          </div>
       </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <div id="site">
           <a href="#">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x150" alt="Mi primer sitio">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <div class="siteContent">
                    <h4>Mi primer sitio</h4>
                    <p>Mi primer sitio, Mi primer sitio, 12345, Mi primer sitio, Mi primer sitio, Mi primer sitio.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>  
          </div>
       </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <div id="site">
           <a href="#">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x150" alt="Mi primer sitio">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <div class="siteContent">
                    <h4>Mi primer sitio</h4>
                    <p>Mi primer sitio, Mi primer sitio, 12345, Mi primer sitio, Mi primer sitio, Mi primer sitio.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>  
          </div>
       </div>

        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </div>
  <footer class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p class="pull-right">Copyright © Todos los Derechos Reservados.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo único que debes hacer es crear un **media querie** para que cuando la página esté en versión móvil el `height` que estás dando al elemento `#allSites` pase de `80vh` a `auto` y así se adapte automáticamente la altura dependiendo de su contenido:

```css
#allSites {
  height:80vh;
}
 
.box-Main {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #c5cacd;
  height:100%;
}

#site {
  max-height: 200px;
  padding: 1em;
  cursor:pointer;
}

#allSites > .col-md-6:hover{
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
/*#site:hover{
background-color: #F2F2F2;
}*/ 

#site a,
#site a:hover{
  color:#31404d;
  text-decoration:none;
}

#site h4{
  font-weight: 800;
}

#site p{
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

#site img{
  margin:0 auto;
  border:1px solid #31404d;
  width: 120px;
  height: 150px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px){
  #allSites {
    height:auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container header">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-3">
            <h1>asfgd</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-3 col-md-offset-4 col-xs-7 col-xs-offset-2  text-right">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-createSite">Añadir sitio</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                <i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-settings">Mis ajustes</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a id="sessionOut" href="#">Cerrar sesión</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid box-Main border-MainTop">
        <div class="row" id="allSites">

      <div class="col-md-6">
         <div id="site">
           <a href="#">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x150" alt="Mi primer sitio">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <div class="siteContent">
                    <h4>Mi primer sitio</h4>
                    <p>Mi primer sitio, Mi primer sitio, 12345, Mi primer sitio, Mi primer sitio, Mi primer sitio.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>  
          </div>
       </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
         <div id="site">
           <a href="#">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x150" alt="Mi primer sitio">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <div class="siteContent">
                    <h4>Mi primer sitio</h4>
                    <p>Mi primer sitio, Mi primer sitio, 12345, Mi primer sitio, Mi primer sitio, Mi primer sitio.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>  
          </div>
       </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <div id="site">
           <a href="#">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x150" alt="Mi primer sitio">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <div class="siteContent">
                    <h4>Mi primer sitio</h4>
                    <p>Mi primer sitio, Mi primer sitio, 12345, Mi primer sitio, Mi primer sitio, Mi primer sitio.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>  
          </div>
       </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <div id="site">
           <a href="#">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/120x150" alt="Mi primer sitio">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <div class="siteContent">
                    <h4>Mi primer sitio</h4>
                    <p>Mi primer sitio, Mi primer sitio, 12345, Mi primer sitio, Mi primer sitio, Mi primer sitio.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>  
          </div>
       </div>

        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </div>
  <footer class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p class="pull-right">Copyright © Todos los Derechos Reservados.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
```